# How to set up a live network?

Tags: live-network

In setting up a live network, starting with a cloud instance running a substrate node. What are the things one needs to keep in mind, in order to make sure they are adhering to best practices?

1. How many ports should be open? Is one for peering and one for websocket enough? Should `ws-external` be required if are only connecting to that node for exploring the blockchain?
2. What if we would like to access that from `polkadot.js.org/apps`? What does one need to do in order to list their node as a test or public network on the block explorer.
3. What about RPC calls? As a sudo key holder, one would like to make sudo calls to the network but I believe it's unsafe to allow `rpc-external` on a public node, so I was thinking of having a local node run a local machine, peer to the cloud instance, and then execute sudo calls.

Comment: You can find some useful information from past Substrate Seminar talks. There were talks about deploying a substrate chain on prod.

Comment: @h4x3rotab do you have a specific link I can visit now?

Comment: this repository was setup as a community initiative to create good practice guidelines for managing the security of blockchain validator nodes https://github.com/w3f/validator-security and the Polkadot wiki includes a section on validator security https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-secure-validator